# Откуда взялся h-файл? Откуда компилятор его берет

Tags: c++

К консольному проекту на языке С++ подключен один h-файл, из
которого подключается другой (второй) h-файл. Все компилируется нормально.
Я попытался установить, где находится второй h-файл? Его нет не только в 
папке проекта, и в папке VS 2010, но и на всем диске С. Откуда же
компилятор берет второй h-файл?

Comment: а он точно подключается? может он включен под директивой условия, и условие не выполняется?

Comment: Как именно файл называется? Какой-нибудь stdafx.h?

Answer (score 6):

Если вы работаете в Visual Studio, определить расположение файла проще простого.

Нажмите правую кнопку мыши на `#include`, выберите `Open Document ...`:

[image: делай раз!]

Откроется нужный файл. Нажмите правой кнопкой мыши на заголовок вкладки с файлом, в меню выберите «Copy Full Path».

[image: делай два]

Всё!

Comment: @Константин: Пожалуйста!